# What can I say about a graph depicting orbit a particle has gone through? Acceleration VS friction

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, classical-mechanics

I have an orbit in which a particle is told to have gone through. There is a straight part, and a curved part. I am asked to mark the right statements, which are:

a. Without any further data, there is no way of knowing in which part of the orbit the acceleration of the particle is zero.

b. The acceleration is non-zero in the curved part, and is zero in the linear part.

c. The acceleration is zero in the curved part, and is non-zero in the linear part.

d. The acceleration is non-zero in the curved part. There is no way to tell if the acceleration is zero in the straight, linear part.

e. The acceleration is non-zero in the curved part, even if there are friction forces.

g. The acceleration is non-zero in the curved part, only if there aren't friction forces.

I am confused a little. At first, it seemed like a,d are true. e seems pretty logical as well, but that undermines what I think of a and d, since, maybe there is only friction and no acceleration? I am confused. What is the actual difference between the two? I haven't yet come by a proper, understandable answer. I though gravity is friction but it is considered acceleration. I would appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The rule is simple: regardless of which forces are acting, if the motion is accelerated then there is a net force, otherwise, there not net force. The only kind of non-accelerated motion is motion in a straight line at uniform speed.
In particular you options:

a)wrong, at  it is accelerated in the curved part. We do not know in the straight part.

b)wrong, it could be accelerated in the linear part also, but we do not know without further information (it depends if it moves at constant speed). It is true that it must be non-zero in the curved part.

c)wrong, the acceleration cannot be non-zero in the curved part (remember zero acceleration means a straight motion with constant velocity). Second statement is correct, we don't know if the straight part is accelerated.

d)correct

e)correct (because it is still a curved, and thus accelerated) path

g) wrong, friction doesn't matter, as far as it is curved, it is accelerated